# Immovable slicers in frozen area?

Tags: excel, scroll, freeze, excel-2013

I have a frozen column with several slicers in the frozen area and some charts on the right of the frozen area. When I scroll left/right the charts move and the frozen column with the slicers doesn't move as designed, but when I scroll down the slicers move up along wit the charts and this is what I want to lock.

Is it possible to lock not only horizontal but also vertical scrolling for the frozen column(s)? Is it possible to have a really frozen area on your worksheet with no scrolling enabled at all?

Comment: Its not possible,  in fact its not possible in either direction,  you are giving it a full columns and locking it , thats why it works, if you give it a full andlock both it would work too, but your table will start  after the slicer in both directions which is not what you want.  Slicers in 2013 dont have an absolute position. you would need to use VBA to reposition the slicer all the time